# firebase.firestore is not a function with Node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently facing a problem with Firebase on my React Native app.
Whenever I try to launch my app, I have the error :"TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function."

I tried many solutions, like importing

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app")
require("firebase/firestore")
```

But it is not working.
My firebase has the latest version.

Here is my code

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

// Initialize Firebase
firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

var firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const st = firebase.storage();
const fr = firebase.firestore();
```

Do you guys have any solutions ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this, do not import all:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
require('firebase/firestore')
require('firebase/storage')

// Initialize Firebase
firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

var firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const st = firebase.storage();
const fr = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer
I tried your code but I am having the same error

Comment: can confirm that firebase (only) is defined? it should work

Answer (score 0):

After a complete check of all my code, I realised that I also called firebase.firestore in another file.
I didn't know that the error was there because the error was not specifying where the error was.